# Query with Contains in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Having trouble using Contains when creating queries. Tried looking it up on oracle docs but everything I have tried keeps giving me an error.

The question is "List all columns of the Product table that contain the words ‘Ink Jet’ in the product name"

My code is

```
 SELECT SCORE(1), PRODNAME
 FROM RCHAMART.PRODUCT
 WHERE CONTAINS(text, 'Ink Jet', 1) > 0;
```

The error is saying that "TEXT" is an invalid identifier but I'm lost at how to go about changing it.

Comment: `CONTAINS(PRODNAME, 'Ink Jet', 1)`

Comment: i tried that as well but it is giving me an error saying that the column is not indexed?

Comment: `CONTAINS()` is for Oracle free text which I assume you're not using - you can simply use `LIKE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use LIKE instead:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM RCHAMART.PRODUCT
 WHERE PRODNAME LIKE '%Ink Jet%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would be sufficient for your:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), PRODNAME
 FROM RCHAMART.PRODUCT
 WHERE PRODNAME like '%Ink Jet%';
```

I think CONTAINS and this special Oracle text indexes are required for large columns (is it your case?).